# From nonnegative sectional curvature to positive sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

We know that Gromoll and Meyer constructed a Riemannian metric of non-negative sectional curvature on an exotic 7-dimensional sphere（this sphere is now called the *Gromoll–Meyer sphere*）in 1974; and Peterson and Wilhelm proved that the Gromoll–Meyer sphere admits a metric of positive sectional curvature in 2008.

> For the smooth Riemannian metric with nonnegative sectional curvature on the standard 7-dimensional sphere $S^7$ (or any higher-dimensional standard sphere), can we deform every Riemannian metric with nonnegative sectional curvature to a smooth Riemannian metric with positive curvature through metrics of nonnegative sectional curvature?

In other words, we have an injection from the space of metrics of positive curvature to the space of metrics of non-negative curvature; does this induce a surjection on $\pi_0$?

Comment: Are you basically asking if the space of metrics on $S^7$ is connected? This is true in general (in fact, the space of metrics is always convex). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I asked if the space of metrics with nonnegative sectional curvature on 7-dimension sphere is homotopy to the space of positive sectional curvature ?

Comment: @Golla: Thank you for your edit! It makes the question clear.